# Java Plugin Framework that will only load from sealed JARS

Tags: java, encryption, plugins, frameworks, cryptography

I am looking to load a JAR at runtime but want loading to fail if the JARs aren't either signed nor sealed. I know that Java JCE has this capability when loading new crypto algorithms. Do any of the plugin frameworks already support this functionality? Otherwise, what is the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSGi has a well defined and logical security model for loading signed jars (dunno about sealed).  Although OSGi is a lot more than just a plugin framework, so you'll find you need a lot of refactoring work.

Well worth the effort tho :)